# Error python TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, lista

Estoy haciendo un programa para que me busque si un numero coincide con el elemento de una lista, y si es así, lo elimine de la lista.

Sin embargo, me sale este error. Os dejo el código:

```
def buscar_en_linea(a11,pos=[1,2,3,4]):
    for i in range(0,3):
       if a11==pos[i]:
           pos=pos.pop(i)
    return pos
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que modificas `pos` con el primer elemento encontrado, con lo que ya no referencia a la lista, sino un entero. De ahí el error.

Nunca es buena idea modificar la colección en la que estás iterando. No sé bien qué es lo que debe hacer la función para ponerte un ejemplo.

Answer (score 0):

No es necesario hacer el for, ya que python te proporciona el operador [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#membership-test-details) que nos sirve para comprobar si un determinado valor esta en una lista, string o clave de un diccionario.

Para borrar un valor de la lista puedes hacer uso del método [`remove`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=remove#array.array.remove)

En tu caso sería algo parecido a este ejemplo:

```
def buscar_en_linea(a11, pos=[1,2,3,4]):
    # Si el numero esta en la lista
    # procedemos a borrar dicho numero
    if a11 in pos:
        # Borrar el numero de la lista
        pos.remove(a11)
        # Devuelves el numero que se ha borrado de la lista.
        return a11
    # En caso que no este devuelves None o el valor que deseas.    
    return None
```

> El método remove lanza la excepción `ValueError` si el valor no existe.

El bucle `for` que estas haciendo esta mal, ya que nunca sabrás la longitud y puede provocar un error, para eso deberías usar la función [len](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len)

Tambien si quieres hacer uso del metodo [`pop`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=remove#array.array.pop), aun que es necesario indicarle el indice del valor y para sacar el indice a partir del valor puedes usar [`index`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html?highlight=remove#array.array.index)

Ejemplo:

```
lista = [1,2,3,4]
lista.pop(lista.index(1))
```

> Si no se indica el indice del valor, el método pop eliminara el ultimo valor de la lista.

Espero que te sea de ayuda.